# Help identifying a M12-like 4-pin connector with 6mm diameter

Tags: connector, cables

I am trying to make a custom cable for a project, but I don't know what kind of connector this is? 
It looks similar to a 4 pin M12 connector but the diameter of this connector is 6mm. Can somebody please let me know the connector type if they are familiar with this kind of connectors?

[image: Top view]
[image: Dimesions]
[image: Side view]

Comment: Do you just need a 4pin connector similar to this, or exactly this one? A side view picture, please?

Comment: Looks a lot like a [LEMO connector](https://www.lemo.com/en/low-voltage-connector/b-connector) to me, but it's hard to tell without a side view.

Comment: I need exactly this connector. Here's a side view picture: 
http://imgur.com/a/kTvEd

Comment: Lemo or fischer, they are pricey

Answer (score 1):

M12 connector IEC 61076-2-101

plug, circular  4-position, shielded, Plug straight M12, D-coded, Crimp connection, Knurl material: Zinc die-cast, nickel-plated, External cable diameter 5 mm ... 8 mm

e.g. http://media.digikey.com/pdf/Data%20Sheets/Phoenix%20Contact%20PDFs/1411046.pdf  no stock

or http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/hirose-electric-co-ltd/HR10A-7P-4PC(73)/HR1663-ND/1095521  then add contacts

Comment: It looks like a M12 connector but the diameter is too small. Is there any 4-pos M8 connector in this type of pin configuration??

Comment: Consult with distributor or website for PhoenixContact and Hirose, but if you only need one.. good luck